# How would we implement interface class in compose without Activity class in Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm fairly new to the compose thing, the last time I worked on Android was way before kotlin was a thing. So I apologize if this is common knowledge but I did look around for a while so I had to turn to the community for some help.

In Java we use

```
public class MyActivityClass implements SomeListnerInterface
```

In onCreate

```
addListener(this)
```

Then just in the activity

```
//overriding the onEventHandler from SomeListnerInterface in MyActivity
@override
public void onEventHandler(){ ... }
```

and we could work with data from this listener

But using compose, we are using `fun MyScreen(){ ... }`, it's not a class anymore. We also use single activity for all the screens, it doesn't make sense to add all these to this activity, does it?
How would we implement the interface (in my case it's a listener) to use inside this composable? So I can also reuse this composable in many areas of my app?

Is there some document I missed that talks about this topic?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What exactly are you calling `addListener` on? Is it some other class? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [CompositionLocal](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal). Ex.

```
val LocalInterface = staticCompositionLocalOf<Interface> { error("Not provided") }

interface Interface { fun log(message: String) }

// Option 1 With Activity
class Activity : Interface {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setContent { Composable(this) }
    }

    override fun log(message: String) { Log.v("Activity", message) }
}

@Composable
fun Composable(inter: Interface) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalInterface provides inter
    ) {
        val inner = LocalInterface.current // Call at any desired level
        inner.log("Message")
    }
}


// Option 2 Direct
class InterfaceImpl: Interface { override fun log(message: String) { Log.v("Impl", message) } }

class Activity {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setContent { Composable() }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Composable() {
    val inter = remember { InterfaceImpl() }

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalInterface provides inter
    ) {
        val inner = LocalInterface.current // Call at any desired level
        inner.log("Message")
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, the second method is what i was looking for. I had everything else but didn't know CompositionLocalProvider. Thanks man!